# Linq query timeout for table

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, lambda

I have many tables that I need to query data to see if a certain parameter(isCorrect) is yes. This field is present in all the tables.
I have built a dynamic query using generic type. But im getting execution period timeout when fetching the data.

Here is a small code snippet:

```cs
public bool isRecordCorrect<T>(Guid userID)
{
    using (EmployeeEntities dbContext = new EmployeeEntities())
    {
        DbSet dbSet = dbContext.Set(typeof(T)) // T here is the table types for e.g            employee, department
        IQueryable<T> query = (IQueryable<T>)dbSet.AsQueryable();
        var list = query
            .Where(DynamicQuery<T>.FilterStatement(userID))
            .FirstOrDefault();
        return list == null ? false : true;
    }
}

public class DynamicQuery<T> 
{

    public static Func<T,bool> FilterStatement(Guid userID)
    {
        var xParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T),  "o");
        var prop = Expression.Property(xParameter, "IsCorrect");
        var incorrect = Expression.Constant("N");
        var equalIncorrect = Expression.Equal(prop,equalIncorrect);
        var userIdProp = Expression.Property(xParameter, "userID");
        var userId = Expression.Constant(userID);
        var equaluserID = Expression.Equal(userIdProp, userId);


        var andExpresion = Expression.And(equalIncorrect, equaluserId);

        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>> (andExpresion, xParameter);
        return lambda.Compile();
    }
}
```

It is timing out for tables which have huge number of records but works okay for others.

Comment: Do you use As No Tracking and Query Splitting? This speeds up the query performance

Comment: Just a thought thought, also, has each table got an index which includes `IsCorrect`? If not the tables are going to be scanned each time.

Comment: Probably you need index for field `userID`.

Comment: @THEoneANDonly, no not yet :/

Comment: @SimonWilson, this field is not indexed yet but every table has this flag

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv, how is that gonna help?

Comment: yeah. every table has it....but the big ones with lots of data are timing out...because there is more data to scan. put a profiler against your db and run the queries. if every table has UserId in it, create an index that holds both userId and IsCorrect. Just try it, takes a second

Comment: first of all check the SQL script generated by this statement. You could either use Linqpad or EF interception to log the SQL script to a console /log file. Then run that SQL script in SQL Mgt Studio to get the Execution Plan. No point just guessing what is going wrong and creating random Indexes on the DB Table. First trace the issue by knowing what is happening.

Comment: This sounds more like a database problem than a code problem. Figure out what query is being executed against the database and optimise from there.

Comment: Also, regarding EF - if all of your tables have the same property, consider making your entity classes implement a common interface. That way you can get rid of that entire `FilterStatement` method

Comment: @SimonWilson, not able to run the profiler in Visual Studio. Database classifies under 'Not Applicable Tools'

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyli, user id or isCorrect?

Comment: @DavidG, sounds a lot of changes

Comment: You do realise that you are iterating over **entire** table? For IQuryable to work you must feed it an Expression, not lambda. When you pass an expression it is converted to DB statement (SQL), then executed, which should take miliseconds. The other thing to notice is you are polluting SQL engine planner with your "const" expression which at high load can make your entire DB timing worse and worse over time because it will not be able to predict efficient plan.

Comment: @eocron, yeah, i wanted it to stop once it gets single record. can you please provide a small snippet?

Comment: @SimonWilson, I have another question. The insert and update operations will however be slowed if table is indexed. These operations are frequently used. And delete also

Comment: Trying to conceal EF behind Generic wrappers then passing expressions is ultimately an exercise in futility. Any parameters or such you pass to build an expression must still conform to EF's rules. A profiler against the DB is a required first step to see what is going on. Firstly, don't use `FirstOrDefault` just to do an Exists check, use `Any()` With `FirstOrDefault` you're still telling EF to waste time returning & filling an entity you never use.  Next, check if client-side evaluation is getting tripped. (If EF Core, esp. older versions where it's enabled by default) This will tank perf.

Comment: @StevePy, so should the code be refactored first?

Comment: Well if a "lot of changes" scares you, then you're probably in the wrong profession! Though getting something done right in the first place is probably a good idea for the future.

Comment: I'd say the first step is the profiler to see what is actually going on. .Net Core would be giving you warnings if client-side evaluation is being triggered. Your aversion to Indexes would also be a concern, possibly premature optimization fears as systems generally read a lot more than they write so there is usually a clear cost-benefit advantage. That said, using GUIDs and indexes can be costly due to fragmentation. Sequential GUID formatting can help, but ultimately the use of a GUID over a Long etc. should be properly justified by a suitable requirement. (I.e. hub-spoke replication)

Comment: @StevePy, which profiler are we refering here?

Comment: OMG, you have applied `Func<>` filter. Missed that at first time. `FilterStatement` should return `Expression<Func<>>`, only in that case EF Core will generate SQL for filtering.

Comment: Depends on the database. If SQL Server, it has a built in profiler you can run to inspect SQL Statements executed, though I tend to run a 3rd party profiler called Express Profiler. It's best if you can profile against a local database instance. Profiling against DB Servers usually requires additional permissions to be set up.

Answer (score 1):

To translate query on the server side, EF Core needs pure Expression. `Compile` and returning `Func<,>`, instead of `Expression<Func<,>>` forces to use `Enumerable.Where` extension, which just loads whole table in memory before filtering. Simple fix should be enough in companion with index on `UserId` (if it is not present).

```cs
public static Expression<Func<T,bool> FilterStatement(Guid userID)
{
    var xParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T),  "o");
    var prop = Expression.Property(xParameter, "IsCorrect");
    var incorrect = Expression.Constant("N");
    var equalIncorrect = Expression.Equal(prop,equalIncorrect);
    var userIdProp = Expression.Property(xParameter, "userID");
    var userId = Expression.Constant(userID);
    var equaluserID = Expression.Equal(userIdProp, userId);


    var andExpresion = Expression.And(equalIncorrect, equaluserId);

    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>> (andExpresion, xParameter);
    return lambda;
}
```

Comment: okay. 1 question. Will it execute the query and from the results take the first one or it stops once it finds the first match?

Comment: Strange question. It will generate `SELECT TOP 1 ...` in your query and will be examined only one record.

Comment: asking because I want to implement COUNT(*) function in expression trees. How will it be?

Comment: It depends on context and is out of scope of this question.